# Geoserver parametrized PostGis database connection fails after upgrade from kartoza/geoserver 2.19.2 to 2.23.1

Tags: geoserver

I have layers based on a PostGis store, where the database credentials are parametrized as environment variables (as described in https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/configtemplate.html). This was working fine in version 2.19.2. But after upgrading to 2.23.1, specifically these layers now fail. When I change the database credentials in the store's datastore.xml back to hard-coded values it works fine again.

The way I pass the .env file is like below. The various env-variables are then processed in datastore.xml as `<entry key="database">${DB_DATABASE}</entry>` etc. As stated, this was working fine in the old version.
[image]

I tried throwing everything Docker-related away and building from scratch. I tried recreating the stores+layers from the new version (from the geoserver interface).

The log file (also when turned up to GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER_LOGGING) shows just this (where 'postgis_db' is the name of the store):
[image]

Comment: what does the logfile say? and what does it say when you turn up the logging level to GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER?

Comment: @IanTurton see edit in question. But afraid that doesn't help much.

Comment: Try GEOTOOLS_DEV?